# -[NSDate dateFromString:]: unrecognized selector sent error

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate

Please help me with the following code. All I want to do is see the time (4:42:55) between two dates that are less than 24 hours different, so I don't care about the days.

Thanks

```
NSLog(@"error code");
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *time = [[NSDate date] dateFromString:@"6:23 PM"];
NSTimeInterval secs = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:time];
NSLog(@"end error code");

int hours = floor((int)secs /  (60 * 60) );        
float minute_divisor = (int)secs % (60 * 60);
int minutes = floor(minute_divisor / 60);
float seconds_divisor = (int)secs % 60;
secs = ceil(seconds_divisor);
NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@:%@:%@", hours, minutes, (int)secs];
```

Here is there Log

```
2011-08-24 22:17:34.827 App[31814:f503] error code
2011-08-24 22:17:34.827 App[31814:f503] -[__NSDate dateFromString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e23d30
2011-08-24 22:17:34.828 App[31814:f503] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate dateFromString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e23d30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1664082 0x17f5d0a 0x1665d1d 0x15caf70 0x15cad52 0x4998 0x392a 0xdef05 0x3f8d3 0x3fb27 0x3fc82 0xc94ec46 0x46b7a 0x23ae 0x179a0 0x18870 0x275f3 0x280a8 0x1ba29 0x130a10d 0x16381f5 0x159d0a2 0x159b98a 0x159ae34 0x159ad4b 0x18271 0x19a1b 0x1ff8 0x1f55)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`dateWithString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithString%3a) is a class method:

```
[NSDate dateWithString:...]
```

However, NSDate on iOS doesn't have this method. You'll have to use an NSDateFormatter with the [`-dateFromString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/dateFromString%3a) method.

Comment: I didn't even notice the alloc. Good catch.

Comment: and I get error "No known class method for selector 'dateWithString:'" (I'm running Xcode 4.2 on iOS 5 Beta 6)

Comment: @michaellindahl Oops, didn't realize iOS doesn't have this. See my updated answer.

Comment: Well that makes things confusing... Thanks for the speedy response time!

Answer (score 0):

Try dateWithString, dateFromString doesn't exist. Which is what the error tells you.

Comment: Then I get a build error. "No known instance method for selector 'dateWithString:'".  Xcode autocompletes (or whatever) dateFromString.

Comment: As @jtbandes points out, it's a class method. Remove the alloc from that line.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
NSDate *time = [NSDate dateWithString:@"6:23 PM"];
```

Comment: I get error "No known class method for selector 'dateWithString:'" (I'm running Xcode 4.2 on iOS 5 Beta 6)

Comment: @michaellindahl: have a similar problem. Works fine on iOS 4.3.3, but crashes on iOS 5.0

Comment: I'm not sure how this worked on iOS 4.3.3 - As @jtbades pointed out in the leading answer to this question, this method was never supported on iOS, only Mac OS. Use the NSDateFormatter's dateToString method instead.